# django : remove ON DELETE CASCADE behaviour of django

Tags: django

I am facing a problem in django development. Actually I am created a Model which include foreign keys of 4 other models . Now I user these all models at at admin site. Problem is that when I delete a record which is used a foriegn key in my main model then this deletion process also delete record from my main model . I required that if a model include a forign key of any other model then if I delete this foreign key model record from admin then no record must be deleted from the model which is using this model as foreign key .

Can any one have idea that how can I stop this 'ON DELETE CASCADE'

I shall be very thank full to you.
Regards

Answer (score 12):

There is `on_delete` attribute for some time, which can be set for `ForeignKey` fields. Example from Django docs:

```
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Answer (score 4):

Override `MyObj.delete()` to iterate through all the keyed relations you want to keep, set their reference back to the object you are deleting to null. Then, once all the relations are unhooked, call `super(MyObj, self).delete()`

You may have to update your database (and model definitions) to allow null=True for those keys you are unhooking.